# Ignore part of sentence with regex

Tags: regex, sas

What I'm trying to do is to ignore parts of a sentence with a regex. 
I'm working with getting the last value of this sentence:

> Gleason score  3+4=7

What's important is that this a just a part of a much bigger picture, so the regex gets this part of the sentence, but why I'm looking for is to only get the value 7.

Per now I've got this regex to mark the whole sentence:

```
Gleason score\s+\d.\d.\d
```

Is there any whay so I ONLY can get the latest value?

Thanks.

Comment: You marked this [tag:sas].  Are you doing this in SAS?  If so, post an example code of how you're extracting the string, and you'll get more useful help.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern

```
[^=]+$
```

explanation:

```
[^=]            # Character not in [=] class
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do. This is generally still more relevant (albeit more difficult) for regexen, as those are not particularly self-documenting.

Comment: Thank you. This works if there is only on sentence, but in my case there is a text document with more sentences and I want to only get the value after "=", where its belong to Gleason score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with positive lookbehind like this:

```
(?<==)\d+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM3qH0/1)**

[image]

You can use capturing group to capture the result by doing:

```
(?<==)(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a lookbehind:

```
(?<=Gleason score \d.\d.)\d
```

Or if any of the stuff you don't want to capture needs to be variable length (e.g. `\s+` or `\d+`) you'll have to use a capture group instead and utilize group 1:

```
Gleason score\s+\d+.\d+.(\d+)
```